# how to replace wild cards in a document with lines from another document?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

how to change a wild card, lets say this one `<x>` and change it for the first line in the other document?

document A: containing wild cards would be like this:

```
<x> text text text
text text text <x>
tex text <x> text
```

document B: containing a list of words to replace.

```
num-1
num-2
num-3
num-4
```

so the desired output would be:

```
num-1 text text text
text text text num-2
tex text num-3 text
```

i really didn't try anything since i don't know how to even start.
but i can guess, it is necessary to read from one file, then another, difficult.

**Update**

Miller take a look at this result: the input is the same as above was provided.

```
 text text text
text text text num-2
 text xt num-3
```

Comment: qtax i din't know how to change it but i noticed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in the second file to build your list of words.  Then just iterate over the first file replacing one "wild card" at a time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file1 = 'foo.txt';
my $file2 = 'bar.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file2;
chomp(my @words = <$fh>);
close $fh;

open $fh, '<', $file1;
while (<$fh>) {
    s/<x>/shift @words/eg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: hi miller, the shell is giving me this : one@one-desktop:~/Desktop$ perl wildmarks.pl

 words words 2
 words.4

Comment: in file foo.txt i do have this: <x> words words <x>
<x> words <x> words.

Comment: Line 9 can be done slightly more succinctly as `chomp (my @words = <$fh>);`

Comment: Aye, the idea of using `chomp` on an array often feels funny to me, so I don't think of it.  Nevertheless, updated.

Comment: miller i added the result below the question, cause here in add coment it loses the format as it is when i copied, i don't understand why is not working , since g modifier is there, should replace all ocurrences.

Comment: @alex This likely has something to do with your exact data, as the code is fine when I use it.

Comment: thanks, my exact data was as the example saved as utf8 linux mode.

Comment: Miller, thanks, i tried your code with cmd under windows and it worked as expected, nor linux but that's ok, that would be another question. works pretty.